# Regex Pattern to parse Maven coordinates

Tags: java, regex, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am attempting to write a Regex pattern to parse Maven co-ordinates from a pom file .

```
[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[?optional_field]:[version]:[compile]

1. org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:0.9.0.M2:compile
2. com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:3.0.0:compile

3. org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile
```

Above are a few example of maven co-ordinates and note that 1 and 2 have a common pattern but 3 has an additional optional co-ordinate

I need a regex pattern to extract groupId, artifactId and version only

Can anyone suggest an appropriate pattern that would work for all three cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of using a regex, you could split by `:` and check the length of the result.
If there are 5 items, then there is no optional field. If there are 6 items, then there is an optional field.

For example:

```
String[] strings = {
    "org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:0.9.0.M2:compile",
    "com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:3.0.0:compile",
    "org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile"
};        

for (String string: strings) {
    String[] coll = string.split(":");
    System.out.println("groupId: " + coll[0]);
    System.out.println("artifactId: " + coll[1]);
    if (coll.length == 5) {
        System.out.println("version: " + coll[3]);
    }
    if (coll.length == 6) {
        System.out.println("version: " + coll[4]);
    }            
    System.out.println();          
}
```

[Output Java example](http://rextester.com/XPLY7340)

Answer (score 4):

I would use the [`aether-api`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/What_Is_Aether) library, because it is the library that parts of maven are based upon. It can safely parse the coordinates and is well tested.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
    <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

E.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DefaultArtifact sisuJar = new DefaultArtifact("org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0");
    System.out.println(sisuJar.getGroupId());
    System.out.println(sisuJar.getArtifactId());
    System.out.println(sisuJar.getVersion());
    System.out.println(sisuJar.getClassifier());
    System.out.println(sisuJar.getExtension());
}
```

will output:

```
org.sonatype.sisu
sisu-guice
3.1.0
no_aop
jar
```

More about eclipse aether [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether).

PS: The coordinates you provided are not valid. If maven tries to parse e.g. `org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile` it says:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad artifact coordinates 
      org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile, 
      expected format is 
      <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version>
at org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:68)
at org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>
```

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is probably what you're looking for:

`([\w\.]+):([\w\-]+):(\w+).*:([\w\.]+):`

There are 3 groups:

1. groupId
2. artifactId
3. version

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/k8WDLm/1